# `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine` exception when jackson-core is upgraded to 2.11.2

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine-cache

I've used `com.fasterxml.jackson.core (v2.8.11)` and `com.github.ben-manes.caffeine (v2.8.1)` maven dependencies in my Spring project.

When I upgraded the `jackson-core` version from `2.8.11` to `2.11.2` I'm getting

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine`

exception. Did anyone face a similar scenario? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade caffeine aswell.
`jackson-core 2.12.2` with `caffeine 3.0.0` is working for me.
If its still not working you could try to reinstall your dependencies. (You could try this first)